# Listas Java (problemas de unificación)

Tags: java, lista, arraylist

Tengo un programa que coge datos de un Excel. Del Excel cojo tres datos por fila, una referencia, un catálogo y una cantidad. Todo eso lo encapsulo en una misma clase (la llamo Dato).
Una vez capturadas todas las filas del Excel, creo los datos y los meto en una misma lista de manera que me queda una lista de datos

```
List<Dato>datos=new ArrayList<Dato>();
```

Teniendo ahí todos mis datos, el siguiente paso es unificar todos aquellos en los que coincida el catálogo y la referencia, y sumar las cantidades de aquellos en las que coincida.

```
for(int i=0;i<datos.size();i++) {
            Dato d=new Dato(datos.get(i).getCatalogo(),datos.get(i).getAlbaran(),datos.get(i).getQty());
            d.setMarcado(true);
            datosBuenos.add(d);

            for(int j=i;j<datos.size();j++) {
                if(datos.get(j).getAlbaran()!=d.getAlbaran() && datos.get(j).getCatalogo()!=d.getCatalogo() && !datos.get(j).getMarcado()) {
                    datosBuenos.add(new Dato(datos.get(j).getCatalogo(),datos.get(j).getAlbaran(),datos.get(j).getQty()));
                    datos.get(j).setMarcado(true);

                }
            }
        }
```

Este es el algoritmo que tengo implementado actualmente (evidentemente, no funciona correctamente, ya que mi array acaba con elementos con el mismo catalogo y referencia, y cantidades de más). Lo que intentaba hacer en él, era guardar en otro array los resultados que consideraba correctos.

El atributo marcado es simplemente un booleano que intenta controlar que ese dato ya se haya tratado, pero tampoco funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No tengo claro como es el objeto Dato, así que te daré una respuesta genérica de cómo agrupar fácilmente y en un solo paso:

En primer lugar, es más sencillo usar un Map que una List para controlar los datos ya leídos, usando como clave/llave el campo por el que quieres agrupar.

Asumamos que la clase datos es así:

```
class Dato {

   ClaseA a;
   ClaseB b;
   ClaseC c;

   //getters & setters...

}
```

Y que quieres agrupar por el atributo `a`. Por tanto declaras un mapa así:

```
Map<ClassA,Dato> map = new HashMap<>(); //por ejemplo, podría ser cualquier otra clase mapa
```

Ahora, cada vez que creas un nuevo Dato, tras leer de la hoja Excel, lo guardas en el mapa:

```
private void guardar(Map<ClaseA,Dato> mapa, Dato d) {
    if (mapa.containsKey(d.getA()) {
      Dato existente = mapa.get(d.getA());
      mapa.put(d.getA(), agrupar(existente, d));
    } else {
      mapa.put(d.getA(),d);
    }
}
```

El método `Dato agrupar(Dato d1,Dato d2)` es el encargado de unir dos datos donde el campo `a` es el mismo, por lo que se está usando como clave en el mapa.

Una vez que tienes todos los datos procesados, puedes hacer

```
List<Dato> datos= new ArrayList<>(mapa.values());
```

Y tendrás la lista de datos agrupados.

Si quieres agrupar por dos campos, dependerá del tipo de los datos, pero en el caso de String o tipos numéricos primitivos, podrías crear una clave de tipo String concatenando ambos campos con un separador:

```
String clave=dato.getA() + " - " + dato.getB();
if (mapa.contains(clave)) ...
```

Comment: Gracias, por la respuesta. Los datos de la clase no son más que Strings (en el caso de las cantidades son enteros). Ya estuve mirando cómo hacerlo con un mapa y la verdad que no pensé en poner como key referencia + catálogo, es una buena idea. Me pondré a implementarlo ahora, pero es sin duda lo que estaba buscando. Muchas gracias